# zend 2 netbeans 7.4 file structure

Tags: php, zend-framework2, netbeans-7.4

I have created a php project in netbeans 7.4 with zend framework 2 and it's running good but I am lost in the file structure. So can somebody help? I am new to Zend 2 -or even zend for that matter-.  PS I am using a Mac

Comment: You using netbeans, right. You first create project in Netbeans and under project name, Source Files folder and Include Path folder will  be created for you respectively . Put all your ZF2 Files under the Source Files folder. That is it.

Comment: @Mubo yeah thx I had done all that. But I am lost in the files -I am a very beginner in ZF-. Basically what I want to know is how to add new models, vews and controllers

Comment: Check out the ZF2 documentation. Every thing you talked about is there . Go through the docs. http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Mubo alright thx for the tip